# How to make desktop browsers ignore the iPhone css3 media query

Tags: iphone, css, xml, media

i'm including an alternate stylesheet for **iPhone/iTouch** devices. Initially i wanted to simply use the `handheld` media type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='handheld'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage.xsl' media='all'?>
```

which i add to the DOM document thusly:

```
//Add handheld stylesheet
ProcessingInstruction pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='handheld'");
doc.InsertBefore(pi, doc.DocumentElement);

//Default css, for everyone else
pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage.xsl' media='all'");
doc.InsertBefore(pi, doc.DocumentElement);
```

Unfortunately, the iPhone's **Safari** browser doesn't support the `handheld` media type. The apple-proposed workaround is to use a **CSS3** media query, replacing `handheld`:

```
media='handheld'
```

with a query that detects iPhone-*like* devices:

```
media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
```

**Note:** 480px is the width of flipped iPhone (i.e. landscape)

So i include this media type in my stylesheet links:

```
//Add handheld stylesheet
ProcessingInstruction pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='handheld'");
doc.InsertBefore(pi, doc.DocumentElement);

//BUG: iPhone doesn't support handheld media type. Use the CSS3 media query hack
pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'");
doc.InsertBefore(pi, doc.DocumentElement);

//Default css, for everyone else
pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage.xsl' media='all'");
doc.InsertBefore(pi, doc.DocumentElement);
```

Which gives the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='handheld'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage.xsl' media='all'?>
```

And all would seem to be good, except that now browsers (ie8, Chrome5) begin using the "handheld" xsl.

"browsers".

> **Note:** Firefox (3.5) doesn't support rendering `xml` content with
>   `xml-stylesheet` at all. What's why i
>   don't include it in the list of
>   "browsers".

---

i've tried moving the "**all**" stylesheet nodes above the iPhone-specific media query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='handheld'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage.xsl' media='all'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage_handheld.xsl' media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'?>
```

But **ie** and **Chrome** continue to use the `only screen and (max-device-wisth: 480px)` media type.

---

How can i have one stylesheet apply for **handhelds**, and another apply for **"everyone else"**.

Answer (score 0):

Not very familar with XML implementation, but here's a good article I just read on doing it just with the media attribute (which leaves out IE users), or instead using a javascript.

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

The short of it is that you ad an ID to the `<link>` something like:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="narrow.css" />`

Then use js to determine the browser window size, and depending on what parameters you want to target, you use the ID as a hood to replace the href value with the appropriate stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few projects that solve this issue that are interesting to this problem:

- [**320 and up**](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/):

  > ‘320 and Up’ prevents mobile devices
  >   from downloading desktop assets by
  >   using a tiny screen’s stylesheet as
  >   its starting point.
- [**Lessframework**](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/):

  > Less Framework is a CSS grid system
  >   for designing adaptive web­sites. It
  >   contains 4 layouts and 3 sets of
  >   typography presets, all based on a
  >   single grid.